# control volumes of multiple independent sound sources

Tags: linux, audio

In linux, how would one have multiple sound sources, which volumes can be controlled independently. For instance you'd have two youtube videos running, and each one would be controlled by something like alsamixer:

```
amixer set X 20%
amixer set Y 60%;
```

The sound of both should then just be merged. Is there a low level solution to this?

Comment: you might look for alsa `plugin:dmix`, though I dont know any more detailis about this.